# Reading input from an HTML form in CherryPy

Tags: python, html, rest, cherrypy

I am looking to read a value from an HTML form into a CherryPy endpoint:

```
class MyWebService(object):

    def generate_random_string(length = 6):
        letters = string.ascii_lowercase
        print("length: " + str(length))
        result_str = ''.join(random.sample(letters, k = length))
        print("Random String is:", result_str)
        return result_str

    @cherrypy.expose
    def index(self):
        return """<form method="POST" action="randomize">
          <input type="text" name="the_link" size="50"/>
          <button type="submit">Randomize!</button>
        </form>"""

    @cherrypy.expose
    def randomize(self, the_link):
        random_string = self.generate_random_string()
        log_statement = link + " converted to: " + random_string
        return log_statement

if __name__ == '__main__':
    config = {'server.socket_host': '0.0.0.0'}
    cherrypy.config.update(config)
    cherrypy.quickstart(MyWebService())
    cherrypy.quickstart(MyWebService(), '/', config)
```

When I run the code and go to `localhost:8080` and type in a value for `the_link`, I see this error:

```
File "app.py", line 25, in generate_random_string
    result_str = ''.join(random.sample(letters, k = length))
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/random.py", line 362, in sample
    if not 0 <= k <= n:
TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'MyWebService'File "app.py", line 25, in generate_random_string
    result_str = ''.join(random.sample(letters, k = length))
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/random.py", line 362, in sample
    if not 0 <= k <= n:
TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'MyWebService'
```

I do not understand why `n` is of type `MyWebService`. Can you point out why? The `generate_random_string()` function works as expected outside of this source file.

Comment: Start by giving `generate_random_string` a "self" argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shoul provide add arguement when you define generate_random_string. When you invoke a instance method. The instance itself was always passed as the first param.

```
class MyWebService(object):

def generate_random_string(self, length = 6):
    letters = string.ascii_lowercase
    print("length: " + str(length))
    result_str = ''.join(random.sample(letters, k = length))
    print("Random String is:", result_str)
    return result_str
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use this Code to get information from a Form:

```
cherrypy.request.params.get('the_link')
```

so your randomize function should be like this:

```
@cherrypy.expose
def randomize(self, *args,**kwargs):
    self.string=cherrypy.request.params.get('the_link')
    random_string = self.generate_random_string()
    log_statement = self.string + " converted to: " + random_string
    return log_statement
```

and your generate_random_string function should be like this:

```
def generate_random_string(self,length=6):
    letters = self.string.lower()
    print("length: " + str(length))
    print(letters)
    result_str = ''.join(random.sample(letters, k=length))
    print("Random String is:", result_str)
    return result_str
```